# how reference unbound combo box in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, datagridview

I'm using the CellClick event and would like to update another checkbox on the grid.
Example:-Two columns with Add and a Delete column.
User clicks Add and the system checks that the delete checkbox is not also checked.
if Delete is checked
------ set Delete to false

In other words the check boxes Add and Delete for the same row must not both be checked.

I'm using...

```
private void customersDataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
```

1. how do I get the value of the current cell by name "Add".
2. how do I get the value of the other cell by name "Delete".
   The above process is a flip/flop.

If I new how to access the cell as an object I should be able to do the rest.

I keep finding example that use `cmbBox = e.Control as ComboBox` but that does not work :(

Links to examples would help thanks.

---

*Added from your suggested edit to the answer -Andomar*

This works...

```
private void customersDataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {   
        //Set a var that determined whether or not the checkbox is selected       
        bool selected = (bool)this.customersDataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Selected;
        //Do the flip-flop here  
        const int add = 4;
        const int delete = 5;
        switch (e.ColumnIndex)
        {
            //If the checkbox in the Add column changed,
            //  flip the value of the corresponding Delete column           
            case add:
                this.customersDataGridView[delete, e.RowIndex].Value = !selected;
                break;
            //If the checkbox in the Delete column changed, 
            //  flop the value of the corresponding Add column       
            case delete:
                this.customersDataGridView[add, e.RowIndex].Value = !selected;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

no need for dataGridView1_CellMouseUp

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. You can also format lists by prefacing lines with a number, a period and spaces. Edit your question and try it out. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting using Markdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the CellValueChanged event instead of the CellClick event. The handler below will set the value of a checkbox according to the opposite value of its counterpart checkbox (i.e. checkboxes that are in the same row).

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        //Set a var that determined whether or not the checkbox is selected
        bool selected = (bool)this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;

        //Do the flip-flop here
        switch (e.ColumnIndex)
        {
            //If the checkbox in the Add column changed, flip the value of the corresponding Delete column
            case 0:
                this.dataGridView1[1, e.RowIndex].Value = !selected;
                break;
            //If the checkbox in the Delete column changed, flop the value of the corresponding Add column
            case 1:
                this.dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex].Value = !selected;
                break;
        }
    }
}

//You may need to do something goofy like this to update the DataGrid 
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        this.dataGridView1.EndEdit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a reminder to any that see this that the...    CellClick works.